# Format a string with a space between every two digits

Tags: python, string, formatting, grouping

Input:
string = 53434951

I need to split up the string so that the output reads:
53 43 49 51

Comment: Cool, what is wrong with your current effort?

Comment: tried some, found on this website but can't find the right one. seems like a simple thing to do that i can't seem to figure out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
s = "534349511"
print ' '.join([s[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(s),2)])
```

Note that this will work for lists of uneven length as well -- you'll just have a single digit at the end, after a space.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for i in xrange(0, len(input), 2):
    out += input[i:i+2] + " "
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def convert(s):
    r = ""
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if i and i %2 == 0:
            r += ' '
        r += c
    return r
```

My solution will not print any extra spaces at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re.findall` also.

```
In [5]: import re
In [6]: s = "53434951"
In [7]: print(' '.join(re.findall(r'.{2}', s)))
53 43 49 51
```

**OR**

Use `re.sub`

```
In [9]: print(re.sub(r'(.{2})(?=.)', r'\1 ', s))
53 43 49 51
```